# How to show different messages during certain time ranges during certain days

Tags: android, kotlin, calendar, android-calendar

Is it possible to show different text within a `TextView` during different days of the week during specific time ranges? I'm trying to do this within decision making statements but I'm not sure what to use as multiple days & times are involved.

1. Monday to Friday, 6am until 9:59am (set text to "Available")
2. Monday to Friday, 10am until 11:59am (set text to "Away")
3. Friday 12pm until Monday 5:59am (set text to "Unavailable")

   ```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
       val current = LocalTime.now()
       val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")
       val currentTime: String = current.format(formatter)
       val currentDay: String = LocalDate.now().dayOfWeek.name

       if (currentTime == "06:00" && currentDay == "MONDAY") {
           tv.setText(R.string.available)
       } else if (currentTime == "10:00" && currentDay == "MONDAY") {
           tv.setText(R.string.away)
       } else {
           tv.setText(R.string.unavailable)
       }
   } else {
       val date = Date()
       val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm", Locale.getDefault())
       val currentTime: String = formatter.format(date)
       val currentDay: String = LocalDate.now().dayOfWeek.name

       if (currentTime == "06:00" && currentDay == "MONDAY") {
           tv.setText(R.string.available)
       } else if (currentTime == "10:00" && currentDay == "MONDAY") {
           tv.setText(R.string.away)
       } else {
           tv.setText(R.string.unavailable)
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest you use a [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library. With it can be written something like this:

```
    fun main() {
        val now = LocalDateTime.now()
        when (now.dayOfWeek) {
            DayOfWeek.MONDAY,
            DayOfWeek.TUESDAY,
            DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY,
            DayOfWeek.THURSDAY -> {
                when {
                    inRange(now, 6, 10) -> tv.setText(R.string.available)
                    inRange(now, 10, 12) -> tv.setText(R.string.away)
                    else -> tv.setText(R.string.unavailable)
                }
            }
            DayOfWeek.FRIDAY -> {
                //todo
            }
            else -> {
                //todo
            }
        }
    }

    private fun inRange(now: LocalDateTime, start: Int, end: Int): Boolean =
        now.isAfter(now.withHour(start)) && now.isBefore(now.withHour(end))
```

you also can use java `Calendar` class but it not so convenient:

```
import java.util.*

fun main() {
    val now = Calendar.getInstance()
    when (now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
        Calendar.MONDAY,
        Calendar.TUESDAY,
        Calendar.WEDNESDAY,
        Calendar.THURSDAY -> {
            when {
                inRange(now, 6, 10) -> tv.setText(R.string.available)
                inRange(now, 10, 12) -> tv.setText(R.string.away)
                else -> tv.setText(R.string.unavailable)
            }
        }
        Calendar.FRIDAY -> {
            //todo
        }
        else -> {
            //todo
        }
    }
}

private fun inRange(now: Calendar, startHour: Int, startMinutes: Int, endHour: Int, endMinutes: Int): Boolean {
    val startTime: Calendar = now.clone() as Calendar
    startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, startHour)
    startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, startMinutes)
    val endTime: Calendar = now.clone() as Calendar
    endTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, endHour)
    endTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, endMinutes)
    return now.after(startTime) && now.before(endTime)
}
```

Comment: Is there any possible way of doing this without using a library?

Comment: yep, but it's less convenient. I've updated my answer

Comment: Okay but I still want to know how it can be done this way.

Comment: I do understand it but I want to see how it is done using the less convenient way as I don’t want to use any libraries in my project.

Comment: You can use the second part of my answer where I'm using a `Calendar`. It's a part of standard Android library so you don't need external libraries

Comment: What about for times in between o'clocks? E.g. 9:25, 9:45, etc.

Comment: my function `inRange` is responsible for it. It creates two instances of `Calendar` and checks is `now` lays between `start` hour and `end` hour. It checks minutes as well

Comment: So for 6:25, what do I change the `6` to?

Comment: I've updated `inRange` function. For 6:25-10:00 you have to call `inRange(now, 6, 25, 10, 0)`